# Issue while using Cloudinary, Carrierwave, Ckeditor with Rails Admin

Tags: ckeditor, carrierwave, rails-admin, cloudinary

I am trying to use Ckeditor with Rails Admin, where I am using Carrierwave and cloud storage as Cloudinary. After making all the settings I can see, CKeditor is able to save the file on local storage and then it creates a Cloudinary URL where the image should actually be stored. But the problem is that the image is not uploaded from that local folder to Cloudinary, whereas my simple file upload works correctly, without any issue.

One more question which I have here is - what should be the storage name when I am using Cloudinary? As for file and Amazon S3, we have names as file and s3.

Please respond.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cloudinary's Ruby GEM includes a plugin for CarrierWave that is used by many of our customers. We are not aware of special issues with Ckeditor (but we haven't tested it though).

When you use Cloudinary's plugin for CarrierWave simply add `include Cloudinary::CarrierWave` to your uploader class. It defines Cloudinary both as the storage engine and image manipulation service (both are cloud-based). Simply **comment out** the `storage :file` line in your uploader class. All images will be uploaded directly to Cloudinary and all transformed versions will be generated using Cloudinary URLs.

Please take a look at the sample uploader code in the documentation page:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration#carrierwave_upload

If the problem persists, it would help if you can share your uploader code so we can help making sure it is defined correctly.

Comment: I am so sorry for not responding.
yes sure here is the code , i have pasted both the uploaded carrierwave as well as the one which I was using for CKEditor. Point to note here if I remove the Storeage :file from Ckeditor uploader I get error and cannot proceed.

https://gist.github.com/3845063

Answer (score 2):

I also have issue with ckeditor. Edit your `CkeditorAttachmentFileUploader` to look similar to this:

```
class CkeditorAttachmentFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  [:extract_content_type, :extract_size, :extract_dimensions].each do |method|
    define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
      send(:"#{method}_without_cloudinary") if self.file.is_a?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
      {}
    end
    alias_method :"#{method}_without_cloudinary", method
    alias_method method, :"#{method}_with_cloudinary"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.attachment_file_types
  end
end
```

After that, you will find another error.
I found that in [Ckeditor::AssetResponse#asset_url](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/ckeditor/asset_response.rb#L89) 
method, the `asset` object is not reloaded, so `asset.content_url` will always be nil thus caused the error. I fixed it like this:

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  ...
  def url_content
    url(:content) || begin
      if persisted?
        reload
        url(:content)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And similarly for `Ckeditor::AttachmentFile` class if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you remove any references to CarrierWave.config.storage = :file

There are a few places you need to do this if this if uploading is not working:

In /config/initializers/carrierwave_init.rb remove all references to:

```
config.storage = :file
```

In your uploaders remove and reference of the sort:

```
storage :file
```